# CanCan I need certain roles to access the entire index and other to only see their index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I am using active admin(devise is included) and I have used cancan to set up my roles. I have an Order model. I have several roles set up. I need certain roles to be able to see the entire order index for all users and then i need certain users to see just their orders with no access to other users orders.

In my orders controller I have this...

```
    scope_to :current_user, :unless => proc{ current_admin_user.admin? }
```

I took that strait from the docs, but it is only showing the admins orders not every order in the index.

here is my ability model

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)

    return if user.nil? #non logged in user can use this.

    if user.admin?
        can :manage, :all
    end

    if user.sales?
        can [:create, :update] [Order, Customer]
        can :read, :all
        cannot :destroy, :all
    end

    if user.production?
        can [:create, :update] [Order, Customer]
        can :read, :all
        cannot :destroy, :all
    end

    if user.art?
        cannot :create, :all
        can :read, :all
        can :update, Order
        cannot :destroy, :all
    end

    if user.broker?
        can [:index, :create, :edit, :update, :read], Order, :id => user.id
        can [:index, :create, :edit, :update, :read], Customer, :id => user.id
        cannot :destroy, :all
    end

    if user.shipping?
        cannot :create, :all
        can :read, :all
        can :update, Order
        cannot :destroy, :all
    end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you are combining rules.

> The ability rules further down in a file will override a previous one.
>   - [Ability Precedence](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence)

As a debugging step, remove everything but the `can :manage, :all`.

If your roles are mutually exclusive, you should use `elsif` instead of separate `if`s.